# difference between @app.route and @auth.route

Tags: python

What is difference between @auth.route and @app.route in the flask app of Python
and what's the use of both that?

I am a freelancer in Python web development so I have a very small but important to know the answer of
that problem so please share me answer as soon as possible  so I can solve my issues

Comment: Please provide a code sample showing both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@app.route` is used to define routes for the main application or the "app" instance in Flask. It is typically used to handle routes that are not specific to a particular blueprint or module. Routes with `@app.route` are accessible throughout the entire application. For example:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello, World!'

@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return 'About page'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In the above example, the routes `/` and `/about` are defined using `@app.route`. They are accessible regardless of any blueprints or modules defined.

`@auth.route` is used to define routes for a specific blueprint or module, often related to authentication or authorization functionality. Blueprints are a way to organize routes and views in larger Flask applications. By using blueprints, you can modularize your application and group related routes together. For example:

```
from flask import Blueprint

auth = Blueprint('auth', __name__)

@auth.route('/login')
def login():
    return 'Login page'

@auth.route('/register')
def register():
    return 'Register page'
```

In the above example, the routes /login and /register are defined using `@auth.route` within the auth blueprint. These routes are accessible only within the context of the blueprint they belong to. To use the blueprint in the main application, it needs to be registered using `app.register_blueprint(auth)`.

Answer (score 0):

In This Question ,
At @app.route

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def check():
    return "hello world"
```

Easily add your routes in your app
but if you have a lot of apis and for that its difficult to choose always different one so, at a time @auth.routes will use it.

on @auth.route , auth is nothing much but name of blueprint

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template

cuser=Blueprint('cuser',__name__,url_prefix="/home")
@cuser.route("/try")
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')
```

here in place of auth use cuser as blueprint name

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).